# How to continuously take from a dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Each time `take` is called, the next set of samples need to be returned.

For example:

```py
ds, info = tfds.load('tf_flowers', with_info=True)
ds = ds['train']
# transform ds here
# ds = ...
list(ds.take(9))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list(ds.take(9))
# returns [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

Note that the image sizes are different, so `batch` cannot be used.

Why is this needed?

I want to use the `show_examples` method or a method similar to it where each time it is called it shows the next set of examples.

```py
tfds.show_examples(ds, info)  # show the first nine
tfds.show_examples(ds, info)  # show the next nine
```

I could `shuffle` the dataset before calling `show_examples` and this would show me a different set each time, but then I'm not able to place these samples back in the original dataset.

Comment: Uh, why not just use `batch` and iterate over the dataset?

Comment: Right.  I should've mentioned that the samples do not all have the same shape.  Edited the question.  Thanks.